# Click event handelr inside a loop

Tags: c#, .net

I have called my clickevent inside a for loop, but as I click my
 PictureBox in this case, for it to open in new form, the click event is
 repeated multiple times, multiple new forms keeps on opening

```
imagename= myRow["Photo"].ToString();
imagepath = imagename.Split(splitchar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 for (int j = 0; j <= imagepath.Length-1;j++ )
 { 
     if(imagepath[j]!=null){

         string imagefinals = paths + imagepath[j];
         pics[j].ImageLocation = imagefinals;
         pics[j].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
         pics[j].Click += new System.EventHandler((s, ee) => LoadImage(s, e, imagefinals));
     }
 }
 return;
```

Comment: Does this happen when the window is opened for the first time or when you load the images the second time from database?

Comment: so whats your issue, this is something obvious in this case to  " the click event is repeated multiple times, multiple new forms keeps on opening"  .As you placed it in the for loop\

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You code makes no sense.  You seem to be iterating over a string `imagepath` and then using those indexes to reference a `pics` collection and adding an eventhandler on those.

Comment: @RePierre yes,the second time,

Comment: @RobKarki, I think the problem is that you don't clear the previous bound event handler before adding a new one. I'll add more details in an answer because the comment box will format the code poorly.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the for loop and if it is fired multiple times, you're stacking up click events. `+=` means  add me to the Invocation list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your input from the comments it seems that you are binding the same event handler each time you are loading the data from database hence the duplication.

Since from the code you've posted it seems that you know beforehand how many `PictureBoxes` you have, you need to split the event handler binding from data binding.

And since you already have the value of `imagefinals` inside the `ImageLocation` property of each `PictureBox` you don't need to pass that to `LoadImage`.

Instead your `LoadImage` method should look like this (at least the beginning of it):

```
private void LoadImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
    if(pictureBox == null)
        return;

    var imageFinals = pictureBox.ImageLocation;
    // rest of the method here...
}
```

Now, given that you already know how many picture boxes you have, in your `FormLoad` method bind the event handlers:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    foreach(var pb in pics)
        pb.Click += LoadImage;
}
```

Otherwise, whenever you add a new `PictureBox` assign the `Click` event handler **but make sure it's in a method that is not called from the code you've posted**.

The next step is to **remove** click event handler binding from the method you posted:

```
imagename= myRow["Photo"].ToString();
imagepath = imagename.Split(splitchar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int j = 0; j <= imagepath.Length-1;j++ )
{ 
    if(imagepath[j]!=null)
    {
        string imagefinals = paths + imagepath[j];
        pics[j].ImageLocation = imagefinals;
        pics[j].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
}
return;
```